# Close Virtual Keyboard programmatically when user hits enter/done

Tags: android, angular, android-virtual-keyboard

I'm currently developing an Angular App that is meant to run on tablets. I have a fake form composed of different lines with a textfield each. I want that when the user types a value inside one of those fields and hits enter the keyboard closes until he hits again a textfield.
Something like: "touch field -> open keyboard -> insert value -> hit enter -> hide keyboard".

Is this possible or is a built-in behavior of Android and it is not avoidable?

Answer (score 0):

You could try dispatching events manually or turning your field into readonly until it is clicked into/refocused again or something like that.